# How to filter a list using Button in Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, list, filter

I have added a column as category in Announcement list and I want to filter the announcement based on category.

I have created no of buttons for the category. I created parameter as Param1 to filter.

But I want to know how to pass the value to Parameter and filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use SharePoint OOB filter web part and connect it to your list. Please have a try and check if it matches your requirement.
[SHAREPOINT 2013 OUT OF BOX WEB PARTS](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/02/12/sharepoint-2013-out-of-box-web-parts/)

[Use SharePoint List Filter in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/use-sharepoint-list-filter-in-sharepoint-2013/)